# 2000 Honda Accord P1167 code

Tags: honda, accord, dtc, code

My Accord threw the P1167 code. I have changed out the 02 sensor. Code went away and then came back. I checked the ecu fuse it is not blown. What else could cause this code to stay on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What engine in your Accord?

Comment: Have you checked for a defect (open circuit, short to ground, bad connection) in the wiring to the O2 sensor and the connectors between the sensor and the wiring?